# sum up data from Access to DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datatable

I have a database that contains a Column of 3 Defined Types and a Column of that contains numbers.
The types can appear severl time in the database.
I want to create a DataTable that will show each type one time only and sum up to numbers that relate to that type.

```
            List<String> types = typesInTable(table);
            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            t.Clear();
            t.Columns.Add("Type");
            t.Columns.Add("Total Expenses");

           foreach (String type in types)
            {
                DataRow tmp = t.NewRow();
                tmp["Type"] = type;
                int total = 0;
                myConnection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = null;
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Type] , [Expense] FROM [" + table+"]", myConnection);
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if(reader["Type"].ToString().Equals(type))
                    {
                        total += Convert.ToInt32(reader["Expense"].ToString());
                    }
                }

                tmp["Total Expenses"] = total;
                if (!t.Rows.Contains(tmp))
                {
                    t.Rows.Add(tmp);
                }
                myConnection.Close();
            }
```

This Code makes the types appear several times.

Comment: why you don't use the SUM function?

Comment: "SELECT sum([Expense]) FROM [" + table+"] where [Type]="+type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to create DataTable that contains every type grouped with the sum :

```
DataTable t = new DataTable();
myConnection.Open();
string query = string.Format("SELECT Type, Sum(Expense) AS TotalExpenses FROM [{0}] group by Type", table);
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
adapter.Fill(t);
myConnection.Close();
```

if You want to sum up the types from different tables all together in 1 DataTable use this:

```
List<String> tableList = serviceMethod.getTableList();
DataTable dtAllType = new DataTable();
foreach (string table in tableList)
{
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
    myConnection.Open();
    string query = string.Format("SELECT Type, Sum(Expense) AS TotalExpenses FROM [{0}] group by Type", table);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(dtTemp);

    for (int i = 0; i < dtTemp.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        bool isDupe = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < dtAllType.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            if (dtTemp.Rows[i][0].ToString() == dtAllType.Rows[j][0].ToString())
            {
                dtAllType.Rows[j][1] = int.Parse(dtAllType.Rows[j][1].ToString()) + int.Parse(dtTemp.Rows[i][1].ToString());
                isDupe = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isDupe)
        {
            dtAllType.ImportRow(dtTemp.Rows[i]);
        }
    }
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

the `dtAllType` `DataTable` contain Type grouped with sum of Expence

Comment: Thank you! and how can I sum up the types from different tables all together?

Comment: how do you get the variable `table` in query ?

Comment: I have a method that return list of tables names in a file - List<String> tableList = serviceMethod.getTableList();

Comment: You want to put all records of tables in one DataTable ?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. all types from all tables grouped and summed up

Comment: I tried it, but it keeps showing the types variuos times..., is there a way the group them?

Comment: You should be have the same type of field `Type` and `Expense` in all Tables

Comment: Abdellah is there other way that we can communicate directly? so I can really elaborate  about my issue.

Comment: I am trying to create another way to make it.

Comment: Ok you can deleted now

Comment: Good, Thank you so Much!

Comment: You can test now the 2nd proposition again!

Comment: I changed again the code to minimize the number of line, you can test it.